# Получение файла с VDS

Tags: java, nginx, ssh, vps, vds

Как получить ссылку на файл, хранящийся на VDS ? Умные люди советуют nginx, я его подключил через SSH, но как настроить я не понимаю, подойдёт и любой другой способ.

Разворачивать сайт мне не нужно, у меня телеграм бот, который сохраняет файл формата csv при нажатии на кнопку, сохраняет в корневой директории, т.е. на vds сервере на котором запущен.

Comment: Сама фраза «ссылка на файл» автоматически подразумевает, что обязательно будет какой-то сайт, на который собственно и будет вести ссылка. Следовательно, читайте любые понравившиеся вам инструкции на тему настройки статического сайта с помощью nginx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В итоге всё оказалось проще чем я думал. Внимательно перечитал метод из telegram bot API который возвращает файл SendDocument, просто передал в конструктор этого метода new File